# Clearing test data from PayPal Sandbox account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to run test using the PayPal rest api and when using the sandbox account I want to create test data, run my test and then remove the test data.

If appears though that payments can be created but not removed.

I can't see a way of doing it but it's pretty hard to test your app without being able to reset your test data when needed.

Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PayPal world (both sandbox and live), transaction records are permanent. They can be reversed, but there is no concept of permanently erasing them.  If you need to start with a blank slate, create a new Business account in the sandbox -- but you should not need to do this.

Comment: I thought as much. It makes sense. Thanks for confirmation. I wanted to write some automated tests around the api. I guess I will use something like https://github.com/vcr/vcr to help with that.

Comment: I would simply run new transactions with new invoice numbers etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can login to your Sandbox developer account and delete the accounts and re-add them.